Hawtio doesn't show JMX tab and MBeans in the UI
recently I've updated my project from java 8 to 17 and decided to refresh the Hawtio from version 1.X to 4.2.0 and for some reason the JMX tab is not visible on the UI. I can see that Jolokia picks up MBeans correctly since I made request to the /jolokia/search endpoint and saw all the Mbeans i wanted with proper versions. I struggle to find similar case on the internet and the official Hawtio docs doesn't really say anything about it too. Jolokia agent as well as the Hawtio is depolyed on the same Wildfly server (as a .war deployment).
Here is the response from /jolokia
{
  "request": {
    "type": "version"
  },
  "value": {
    "agent": "2.0.3",
    "protocol": "7.3",
    "details": {
      "agent_version": "2.0.3",
      "agent_id": "someId",
      "secured": false,
      "url": "someURL"
    },
    "id": "someId",
    "config": {
      "agentId": "someId",
      "allowErrorDetails": "false",
      "includeStackTrace": "false",
      "mbeanQualifier": "qualifier=hawtio"
    },
    "info": {
      "proxy": {},
      "jmx": {}
    }
  },
  "status": 200,
  "timestamp": 1732550404
}

What can be the cause of such problem?
I've tried to alter the configuration, creating a hawtio.properties with hawtio.plugins=org.hawtio.jmx inside of it and then putting it into the WEB-INF/classes/ of my hawtio.war. Since there is so little information in the Hawtio docs I couldn't find any other method I could use to solve my issue.

[Solution] Actually, there was a problem with TLS termination proxy and hawtio couldn't connect via https with jolokia agent that was on a pod with traffic opened through http. The solution was to add this jolokia property (https://hawt.io/docs/configuration.html#_configuring_jolokia_through_system_properties) as well as add your own jolokia-access.xml with the configuration of CORS similar to this https://github.com/jolokia/jolokia/issues/731
